# How to retrieve Anaconda package metadata via API call?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

We need to fetch metadata of Python packages, in particular the license field. `PyPi` has a convenient REST API route `https://pypi.org/pypi/{package}/{version}/json` (e.g. `https://pypi.org/pypi/numpy/1.1.1/json`) which responds with metadata. Is there a similar API endpoint of (Ana)conda?

The CLI command `conda search "{package}={version}" --json` queries the metadata on the command line. Unfortunately, the requirement is to not rely on a local installation of conda.

Comment: You could look at the `repodata.json` of the respective channel, e.g. https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/repodata.json see https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/3.21.x/concepts/generating-index.html

Comment: Can you explain the use for this, what exactly are you looking for.

Comment: The use case is to fetch the licenses of (publicly available) packages which are in use in our repositories and process them programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving Anaconda package metadata via API call involves using the Anaconda Cloud API. You can make a request to the following endpoint:
[https://api.anaconda.org/package/{username}/{package_name}](https://api.anaconda.org/package/%7Busername%7D/%7Bpackage_name%7D)
Replace {username} with the Anaconda username and {package_name} with the specific package name you're interested in. Use standard HTTP methods like GET to retrieve information.

For example, if you want metadata for a package named "example_pkg" owned by a user "user123," the API call would be:
https://api.anaconda.org/package/user123/example_pkg
Ensure you have the necessary permissions and handle authentication if required for private packages.

https://www.oliveboard.in/blog/

Answer (score 0):

For having a basic look at the package SHA code, release code, Size, MD5. you can check at https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/  For any other OS https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think Conda have a direct API (equivalent to the PyPI JSON API) for fetching package metadata (Correct me if I am wrong). Conda primarily relies on local package and environment management.

Comment: See @Sourabh's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77366340/3986677. Anaconda has a public API for package metadata.